# What are the differences between all the player characters?

Tags: pocket-mine

I just unlocked a second miner called Penny.

Is there any significant difference between Hunter and Penny other than cosmetics?

What are the differences between all the player characters?

[See screenshots below... "Hunter: Born for this" & "Penny: A bit of a finesse"]

[image]

## VS.

[image]

Comment: You should change this question to, *"What are the differences between all the player characters?"* (Also if your interested in sharing trophies ect, I play this as well)

Comment: @Ender Good call

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll notice that Penny's goals are 1/2 what the goals normally are.  I forgot to read the description for her before I released her, but that seems to be the case.  The robot's skill is a permanent magnetic charge.  Sven's skill is pick durability +20%.  The mummy just lets you dress as a mummy as far as I can tell.  I have also uncovered Pilgrim, which lets you dress as a pilgrim.  Greedy Goblin doubles cash rewards.

Comment: can you site a source to this?